# How to query from two tables in codeigniter using active record?

Tags: codeigniter

Hi friends How do we query from two tables in codeigniter using active record ? Can anyone pls show me how to insert in the fields of  two  tables while adding fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just use separate queries.

For selecting:

```
$query1 = $this->db->get('table1');
$query2 = $this->db->get('table2');
```

For inserting

```
$data1 = array(
               'title1' => 'My title1' ,
               'name1' => 'My Name1'
            );

$this->db->insert('table1', $data);
$data1 = array(
               'title2' => 'My title2' ,
               'name2' => 'My Name2'
            );

$this->db->insert('table2', $data);
```

Comment: is there a way to bind query in one statement for advance select statements like joins etc ?